# fr4 electrical conductivity @ 36 MHz

Tags: pcb, simulation

I am trying to simulate a standard FR4 PCB, but one of the parameters I need to provide is the electrical conductivity of the material. I know I can extract it from the dissipation factor or the tangent loss. However, I can't find any data @ 36 MHz.

What is a good reference to find this value?

Comment: 0.02 is common , what do you need? and what coating and %RH moisture stress level is this?

Comment: This one is lower https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1644697.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response @TonyStewartEE75 The lower the loss the better. I don't have a particular value I need to keep under. I'm just trying to model my board as accurate as possible. I will use 0.02 for now.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - why do you need to know the G of FR4?

Comment: Hey @Andyaka I am basically trying to calculate the loss of a sensitive resonator that's on the top layer of the board.